# PGSQL driver not found in Laravel PHP Framework

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo, laravel

Hi I am using Laravel PHP framework on CentOS 6.3. I have PostgreSQL 9.1 installed, along with PDO and PDO-PGSQL. Under `application/config/database.php` I have set Laravel to use PostgreSQL:

```
'default' => 'pgsql',


'connections' => array(

    'pgsql' => array(
        'driver'   => 'pgsql',
        'host'     => 'localhost',
        'database' => 'dbname',
        'username' => 'username',
        'password' => 'shhhpass',
        'charset'  => 'utf8',
        'prefix'   => '',
        'schema'   => 'public',
    ),
),
```

However, visiting any page gives me the error:

```
Message:

could not find driver
Location:     

/home/dev/public_html/laravel/database/connectors/postgres.php on line 37
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The line giving that error is this:

```
$connection = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $this->options($config));
```

It is trying to load the PDO driver for pg.

Did you check that the pdo extension is enabled in PHP configuration files?
Check the `/etc/php.d/pgsql.ini` and `/etc/php.d/pdo.ini`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Note: After installing the PDO driver one needs to restart Apache for the changes to be effected: `sudo systemctl restart httpd.service`

Answer (score 7):

Run `sudo apt-get install php5-pgsql` on your terminal.

In other words, install the PostgreSQL driver for PHP.

Comment: The OP stated that he is using CentOS. These instructions are for Debian/Ubuntu.